# Shortcut for MutableMap/HashMap

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a slightly long class type: `MutableLiveData<MutableMap<String, List<MyItems>>>`.
is it possible to make `MutableMap<String, List<MyItems>>` shorten with some kind of a data class or something like that without adding a lot of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not be fully understanding the ask but could you just use something like:

```
typealias YourMapType = MutableMap<String, List<MyItems>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyMap extends MutableMap<String, List<MyItems>> {}
```

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't I implement all its members?

Comment: It depends what is the MutableMap, is it a concrete class or abstract or an interface?